# User-input does not match output of object list attributes

Tags: python, arrays, list, class, attributes

So I've been making a simple program where you can select cars and buy/sell them, and they get stored in the inventory. Additionally, you can ask for specific attributes of what you want in your car. The code is as followed:

```
class Consumer:
  #create an inventory to store cars
  garage = [] 

  def __init__(self, budget):
    self.budget = budget

  #returns current budget of user
  def checkBudget(self):
    return self.budget

  #take money away from the budget and store the car in the inventory
  def buy(self, car):
    self.budget = self.budget - car.price
    self.garage.append(car)

  def sell(self, value):
    #takes back original money and takes out car
    self.budget = self.budget + self.garage[value].getPrice()
    return self.garage.pop(value)

  def showGarage(self):
    for i in self.garage:
      print(i.getInfo())

  def carCount(self):
    return len(self.garage) - 1


class Car:
  def __init__(self, model, color, price, year):
    self.model = model
    self.color = color
    self.price  = price
    self.year = year

  def getName(self):
    return ("{} {} from {}".format(self.color, self.model, self.year))

  def getInfo(self):
    return ("{} {} from {} that costs ${}".format(self.color, self.model, self.year, self.price))

  def getColor(self):
    return self.color

  def getYear(self):
    return self.year

  def getPrice(self):
    return self.price




class Sedan(Car):
  def __init__(self, model, color, price, year):
    super().__init__(model, color, price, year)
  
  def colorPrice(self, color):
    self.color = color
    self.price = self.price + 200
  

class SUV(Car):
  def __init__(self, model, color, price, year):
    super().__init__(model, color, price, year)
  
  def colorPrice(self, color):
    self.color = color
    self.price = self.price + 300


class Sports(Car):
  def __init__(self, model, color, price, year):
    super().__init__(model, color, price, year)

  def colorPrice(self, color):
    self.color = color
    self.price = self.price + 800
  

class Bike(Car):
  def __init__(self, model, color, price, year):
    super().__init__(model, color, price, year)

  def colorPrice(self, color):
    self.color = color
    self.price = self.price + 400

class Catalogue:
  #placeholder to store all cars
  whole = []
  #sets user-defined preferences of cars
  preferences = []

  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def addCars(self, car):
    self.whole.append(car)
    self.preferences.append(car)

  #shortens list so that the catalogue shows only the cars from the year the user wants from
  def year(self, year):
    for i in self.preferences:
      if int(i.getYear()) != int(year):
        self.preferences.remove(i)
    if not self.preferences:
      print("There are no cars from this year")
      self.Reset()
      print(self.preferences)

  #shortens list so that the catalogue shows only the cars of a certain color
  def color(self, color):
    for i in self.preferences:
      if str(i.getColor()) != str(color):
        self.preferences.remove(i)
    if not self.preferences:
      print("There are no cars of this color")
      self.Reset()
      print(self.preferences)

  #shortens list so that it only shows the price range
  def price(self, low, high):
    for i in self.preferences:
      if int(i.getPrice()) <= int(low) or int(i.getPrice()) >= int(high):
        self.preferences.remove(i)
    if not self.preferences:
      print("There are no cars from this price range")
      self.reset()

  #clears all preferences so that it shows all available cars
  def Reset(self):
    self.preferences.clear()
    for i in self.whole:
      self.preferences.append(i);

  def showCatalogue(self):
    for i in range(len(self.preferences)):
        print(self.preferences[i].getInfo())
  
  def getLength(self):
    return len(self.preferences)
  
  #gives the car away
  def sell(self, value):
    self.whole.pop(value)
    a = self.preferences.pop(value)
    return a
  
  


showcase = Catalogue()
Toyota = Sedan('Toyota Camry', 'blue', 64000, 2002)
Honda = Sedan('Honda Civic', 'red', 65000, 2002)
Dodge = SUV('Dodge Durango', 'black', 4324, 2015)
Yamaha = Bike('Yamaha x', 'red', 23240, 2015)
showcase.addCars(Toyota)
showcase.addCars(Honda)
showcase.addCars(Dodge)
showcase.addCars(Yamaha)

customer = Consumer(100000)

#garage module
def garage():
  global customer
  global showcase
  a = input("What do you want to do? 1) check car collection 2) sell car  3) back ")
  #shows all cars from the inventory
  if int(a) == 1:
    customer.showGarage()
    garage()
  #sells available cars
  elif int(a) == 2:
    customer.showGarage()
    #will cancel if there care no cars in the inventory
    if len(customer.garage) == 0:
      print("You have no cars")
      garage()
    else:
      #enter index no to select a car
      b = input("Pick a car from 0 to {} ".format(customer.carCount()))
      if int(b) > int(customer.carCount()):
          print("You don't have that many cars!")
          garage()
      else:
        c = input("Are you sure you want to sell this car? 1) yes 2) no ")
        #asks for warning confirmation
        if int(c) == 1:
          d = customer.sell(int(b))
          showcase.addCars(d)
          print("This car has been sold; have a nice day!")
          garage()
        elif int(c) == 2:
          garage()
  #go back to main
  elif int(a) == 3:
    e = input("Are you sure you wanna go back? 1) yes 2) no ")
    if int(e) == 1:
      main()
    elif int(e) == 2:
      garage()
  


#asks if you want to specify the list
def access():
  global showcase
  showcase.showCatalogue()
  print()
  g = input("Looking for specifics? 1) yes   2) no: ")
  if int(g) == 1:
    options()
  else:
    choose()
  print()

#would you like to access catalogue or garage?
def main():
  a = input("Where do you want to go next? 1) check garage   2) browse more cars" )
  if int(a) == 1:
    garage()
  elif int(a) == 2:
    access()
  else:
    print("Try again")
    main()


#car purchase confirmation
def buy(car):
  global customer
  global showcase
  a = input("Are you sure you want to buy this car? 1) yes  2) no " )
  if int(a) == 1:
    #cancels purchase automatically if your balance is low
    if int(customer.checkBudget()) < int(showcase.preferences[car].getPrice()):
      print("You do not have enough money")
      access()
    else:
      #takes the car out of the catalogue and stores it in the garage
      print("Transaction taking place...")
      sold = showcase.sell(car)
      customer.buy(sold)
      print("You purchased this car")
      print("You now have a budget of {} dollars".format(customer.checkBudget()))
  main()
  
  
    
def choose():
  #which car you would like to purchase
  global showcase
  c = input("Which car would you like? enter from 0 to {} ".format(showcase.getLength()-1))
  if int(c) > int(showcase.getLength()):
    print("Out of bounds, please try again")
    choose()
  else:
    buy(int(c))



def options():
  #which specifics are you looking for?
  global showcase
  a = input("What are you looking for? 1) color  2) price  3) year: 4) reset ")
  if int(a) == 1:
    b = input("Pick a color: ")
    showcase.color(b)
  elif int(a) == 2:
    b = input("Pick a lower price range: ")
    c = input("Pick an upper price range: ")
    if showcase.price(b) > showcase.price(c):
      print("Invalid Error") 
    else:
      showcase.price(b,c) 
  elif int(a) == 3:
    b = input("Pick a year: ")
    showcase.year(b) 
  elif int(a) == 4:
    showcase.Reset()
  else:
    print("Invalid, try again")
    options();
  access()

access()
```

My main issue is with the specifics. For example, when I type for a blue car, it gives me a black car. When I type for a car from 2015, it gives me a car from 2002. When I ask for a car no more than $50000, it gives me a car worth $65000. Here are some runtime scenarios:

```
What are you looking for? 1) color  2) price  3) year: 4) reset #1
Pick a color: #blue
#returns
blue Toyota Camry from 2002 that costs $64000
black Dodge Durango from 2015 that costs $4324
```

```
What are you looking for? 1) color  2) price  3) year: 4) reset #3
Pick a year: #2015
#returns
red Honda Civic from 2002 that costs $65000
black Dodge Durango from 2015 that costs $4324
red Yamaha x from 2015 that costs $23240
```

The code problem can be found here:

```
  #shortens list so that the catalogue shows only the cars of a certain color
  def color(self, color):
    for i in self.preferences:
      if str(i.getColor()) != str(color):
        self.preferences.remove(i)
    if not self.preferences:
      print("There are no cars of this color")
      self.Reset()
      print(self.preferences)

  #shortens list so that it only shows the price range
  def price(self, low, high):
    for i in self.preferences:
      if int(i.getPrice()) <= int(low) or int(i.getPrice()) >= int(high):
        self.preferences.remove(i)
    if not self.preferences:
      print("There are no cars from this price range")
      self.reset()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are trying to remove items from a list which is being looped through. This may create unexpected behavior. Store the values to be removed and then later remove from the list, something like this

```
def color(self, color):
    tobeRemoved = []
    for i in self.preferences:
      if str(i.getColor()) != str(color):
        tobeRemoved.append(i)
    for pref in tobeRemoved:
        self.preferences.remove(pref)
    if not self.preferences:
      print("There are no cars of this color")
      self.Reset()
      print(self.preferences)
```

I was able to get the output you wanted

```
blue Toyota Camry from 2002 that costs $64000
red Honda Civic from 2002 that costs $65000
black Dodge Durango from 2015 that costs $4324
red Yamaha x from 2015 that costs $23240
Looking for specifics? 1) yes   2) no: 1
What are you looking for? 1) color  2) price  3) year: 4) reset 1
Pick a color: blue
blue Toyota Camry from 2002 that costs $64000

Looking for specifics? 1) yes   2) no:
```

You can do the same for `price()` also